# Run angular dist without ng serve

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-builder

I have very custom build process for my Angular app. I configured Webpack myself and do not use any internal build tool which is provided inside Angular CLI.

Now i would like to run my build in browser, but under specific host address and port.
for example: `dev.someurl.com` and port `443`.

I tried Serve package from NPM, but was not able to configure it's host. it is always run on localhost.

Do you have any suggestion how to run the dist/bundle under specific host and port ?

Comment: `lite-server` should do the trick (has both host and port options)

Comment: or use `http-server`, which also has  hostname (`-a`) and port (`-p`) options